# How to extract string that appears after certain pattern?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have strings like:

```
str1 = "Information name: Wen Moyes address: Mcity."
str2 = "resume Name : Sam Win Father's name: Dean address"
str3 = "Father's name: Dan. Acknowledge"
str4 = "Father's Name: Joe Cena Name :- John Cena"
```

I want to extract names from each of the string that follows after Name. If string contains `Father's name` it should ignore that part and only look for `name`

**My expected output is**:

```
Wen Moyes
Sam Win
None
John Cena
```

**What I tried**:

I used below `regex`

```
re.findall(r'name\s*:(\s*\w*\s\w*)', str1.lower())
```

which is giving me output as:

```
[' wen moyes']
[' sam win', ' dean address']
[' dan']
[' joe cena']
```

How can I handle this?
Is there an alternative way without using regex?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the conditions are. For example, why doesn't "Joe Cena" (or "Joe Cena Name") qualify?

Comment: coz it's father's name. I want to extract only Names. wait I'll edit my question for more clarification.

Comment: That is some *very* loosely structured input. It's gonna be pretty tough to parse that reliably. And why isn't `Dan. Acknowledge` included in the expected output?

Comment: @deceze I have already edited my question to explain why it doesn't qualify. You can look at it.

Comment: hi brother this not clear, if you have two fields in string you must mention a separator like str1 = "Information name: Wen Moyes, address: Mcity." then you can easily split this

Comment: @vijinselvaraj: My input is not well structured to divide it using separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to negative lookbehind for `Father's`, then match `Name:` with optional spaces/dashes, and then capture the following `(\w+ \w+)`:

```
str1 = "Information name: Wen Moyes address: Mcity."
str2 = "resume Name : Sam Win Father's name: Dean address"
str3 = "Father's name: Dan. Acknowledge"
str4 = "Father's Name: Joe Cena Name :- John Cena"

pattern = re.compile(r"(?<!Father's )[Nn]ame ?:-? (\w+ \w+)")
for str in [str1, str2, str3, str4]:
    print(re.findall(pattern, str))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Gp5PDr/1

Comment: this is what I was looking for. I was not sure how to negative look behind for particular word. Thanks :-)